# copy pointer values *a = *b in golang

Tags: go

```
type T struct {
    Id int
    Name string
}

func Copy(a *T, b *T) error {
    b.Id=5
    b.Name="gert"
    a = b
    return nil
}
```

`a` is still empty, I have to do it like this

```
func Copy(a *T, b *T) error {
    b.Id = 5
    b.Name = "gert"
    a.Id = b.Id
    a.Name = b.Name
    return nil
}
```

now `a` is the same as `b`

Why and how can I copy `*b` to `*a` directly?

Comment: The Golang core language only provide the hard-copy way: `*a = *b`.  If someone want's an Object Oriented style which is more commonly used (such that clone's behavior is object-type specific), see my raised question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639328/could-anybody-provide-your-own-standard-convention-of-clone-method-that-work-w

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Your first example is almost right. You pass in pointers to two objects. You put those pointers into variables A and B. But A and B are local variables, so when you say `a=b` you are merely saying "forget what was in A (locally)". The rest of the program still has pointers to those two original objects.

If you want to copy the *data structure* at B into the *data structure* at A, do this instead:

```
*a = *b;
```

As dmikalova pointed out in the comments below, this merely copies the structs -- but not any data the struct points to. If your struct has a pointer, the data it points to is now shared by the two copies (because it only copied the pointer).

Technically, strings are always pointers, so they are never copied as part of your struct. **But** because strings are immutable (and Go has Garbage Collection), strings "feel" like they are part of your struct, and you don't have to worry about the low-level string sharing that magically saves you memory without you having to think about it.

Comment: lol :) tried `a=*b` and `*a=b` and the thing I typed in the title `*a=*b` I didn't haha

Comment: Is this actually copying the data structure, or just setting the pointer a to point to the same place as the pointer b? After this assignment, will changes to b also happen to a? If so, that's not copying, but simply assignment.

Comment: Read what I wrote. `*a = *b` is copying data from the memory of one struct (pointed to by b) onto the data of another struct (pointed to by a). They continue to remain distinct areas of memory, so updates will not propagate.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard You start with `a != b` by assumption, so `*a` and `*b` are at different places in memory. The assignment `*a = *b` doesn't modify `a` or `b` so you end up with `*a == *b` but still have `a != b`.

Comment: One surprise you may have with this is that it's a shallow copy - so if any of the fields on b are pointers then it is those pointers that will be copied to a. Any maps or structs won't be deeply copied over.

Comment: @kbolino Until your comment I thought I got it. This really f***** my brain now.

Comment: It panics if `a == nil`

Answer (score 21):

**Generic solution for framework developers :**

```
func Copy(source interface{}, destin interface{}) {
    x := reflect.ValueOf(source)
    if x.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        starX := x.Elem()
        y := reflect.New(starX.Type())
        starY := y.Elem()
        starY.Set(starX)
        reflect.ValueOf(destin).Elem().Set(y.Elem())
    } else {
        destin = x.Interface()
    }
}
```

So:

```
Copy(old, new)
```

[see this code in play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/b1lylpDL98)
 So you can pass any type at run time as long as you're sure that source and destin are both of the same type, (and destin is a pointer to that type).

Comment: U could test it before voting down.

Comment: Probably down voted because of the use of reflect, stil think it should not be down voted so I up voted it again to compensate, but maybe add more text that its not the recommended way to do it this way, just extra information about pointers.

Comment: This code doesn't work unless source and destin are both pointers (destin needs to be pointer if you want to update the value outside of the function). You could fix the code to allow source to not be a pointer by using   
`reflect.ValueOf(destin).Elem().Set(x)` instead of `destin = x.Interface()`.  


Working version of above code: https://play.golang.org/p/WcOfcrV4q5.  


Still needs more error checking (check both are the same type for example).

Comment: The example panics when `CloneValue(old, 5)`

Comment: @zerkms:It should panic in that situation. you should take care of preconditions before using it.This solution should be used when you have no idea about what type of structure you are cloning (at run time), but you shouldn't let the state of your app to be invalid. And invalid here means the situation that your parameters are different.

Comment: "you should take care of preconditions before using it" --- I think it's wrong from the very beginning: if you decided to opt-out from the type-safe implementation provided by a type system and a compiler then it's your responsibility to take into account all edge cases by yourself.

Comment: @zerkms:Take a look at the definition of precondition in this paper: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Projects/P1/proj1.contract.html. Not every language support all type-safe features you need.What should we do when go doesn't support generics? And why does go let us get the `reflect.ValueOf(aNonPointerVariable).Elem()`. Please make me correct if I'm not in a right rode @zerkms.Thank you.

Comment: @zerkms:`reflect.ValueOf(5).Elem()` panics as well.So I need to use it in a right situation.

Comment: @zerkms:I can see what you mean I provided more information in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: How about just marshalling and then un-marshalling to the new struct? very simple if not 'pure' or performant.

Comment: @rjarmstrong:Yes that can work as well but I hate `json notations` to be appeared at my domain objects.

Comment: Brilliant ! helped me a lot. exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 16):

In go, arguments are passed by value.

and *T is a pointer to a T.  Think of it as an int that tells you where that T is.
So, "a" points to one instance of T and b points to another.

in your copy function, you are saying make a point to b's "T" (if that made sense).
What you wanted was to say that a's T should be the same as b's T

You do that by dereferencing the pointers.

so, instead of a = b (change my local variable "a" to point to whatever "b" points to)
you use *a = *b (change a's T to be equal b's T)

Hopefully that made sense, here's an example of your app modified to "do the right thing".  Note, your Copy function isn't necessary in this, it's there for illustration.  [Play example](http://play.golang.org/p/_tsZ5wUsdI)

```
import "fmt"

type T struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
}

func Copy(a *T, b *T) error {
    b.Id = 5
    b.Name = "gert"
    a = b
    return nil
}
func CopyThatActuallyCopies(a *T, b *T) error {
    b.Id = 5
    b.Name = "gert"
    *a = *b
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var a = &T{1, "one"}
    var b = &T{2, "two"}

    fmt.Println(a, b)
    Copy(a, b)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
    CopyThatActuallyCopies(a, b)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This is wrong.It does not work

```
func (r *Request) WithContext(ctx context.Context) *Request {
  if ctx == nil {
    panic("nil context")
  }
  r2 := new(Request)
  *r2 = *r
  r2.ctx = ctx
  return r2
}
```

Comment: You should consider adding a little more explanations, as it is is, the response appears unclear.

Comment: Please add explanation to your solution. Giving solution without explanations is useless.