# Could anybody provide your-own/standard convention of "clone method" that work well for my/our reference?

Tags: go

I can't find a "clone" method convention in Golang, but it seems necessary to have one.

I only saw the built-in way `*clonedObj = *obj`, but it is too low-level, and can't handle (when-necessary) deep copy of case like `struct { member *CompositionObj }`

I doubt whether "func (obj ClassA) Clone() interface{}" prototype will work, because calling `obj2 := obj.Clone()` will "loose" the method set for ClassA, and need explicit code like `obj2.(*ClassA)` afterwards.

Please advice a working direction.

Comment: Remark:  I am seeking some general solution, e.g. a practical method signature for copying;  not some specific solution, like always deep-copy everything.

Comment: Reason for downvote?  I think Go community should have paradigm to such so-common programming problem.  It is just copy constructor in C++, clone in Java, etc.  Do anyone agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, having some while no one else give me proper reference, I have found out some reference example how to clone in Go myself and want to share.

(Only upvote me a few if this answer is useful to you.  I'm not for earning votes.  Welcome other better answers and comments)

I found this protoype in package "github.com/jinzhu/gorm" (Database's ORM library) for reference:

```
func (s *DB) clone() *DB {
    db := &DB{
        ...
    }
    ...
    return db
}
```

And similar pattern in package "golang.org/x/net/html/atom":

```
func (n *Node) clone() *Node {
    m := &Node{
        Type:     n.Type,
        ...
    }
    ...
    return m
}
```

The above prototype is enough if the Clone()'s caller always know your object type when cloning.  (and you need uppercase `Clone()` to make the method to be "public")

However, if you want advanced feature that a variable may hold any object of similar base interface, here is my sample:

```
func (t *T) Clone() YourBaseInterface
```

Where YourBaseInterface is:

```
type YourBaseInterface interface {
    Clone() YourBaseInterface
    OtherMethod1()
    ...
}
```

Or can merely use `interface{}` instead of `YourBaseInterface` in the return, and do a typecast like `obj2 := obj.Clone().(*YourBaseType)` after clone.

### CAUTION

There is one drawback with this prototype.  Becase Golang doesn't support this prototype as build-in, the `Clone()` method won't be called in some language's feature, e.g. when you `copy(dest, src)` a `[]YourTypeWithClone` slice.  Instead, it still do plain `*elem2 = *elem1` struct copying.  Solutions maybe either don't use those build-in, or you may flaw back to design the class struct members so that doing plain copy is enough for its copy purpose if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28579297/6276385) to a similar question regarding maps suggests to use [the gob package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/). The documentation states:

> A stream of gobs is self-describing. Each data item in the stream is preceded by a specification of its type, expressed in terms of a small set of predefined types. Pointers are not transmitted, but the things they point to are transmitted; that is, the values are flattened. Nil pointers are not permitted, as they have no value. Recursive types work fine, but recursive values (data with cycles) are problematic. This may change.

so it may not be suitable for your use case.

That said, your question largely depends on your actual use-case. You do not need a generic way to deep-copy things usually, you can usually either get away with the built-in copy mechanics or write concrete copy functions for the types that actually need it.

An alternative might be [the deepcopy package](https://godoc.org/github.com/getlantern/deepcopy) but I have no experience with it myself, I just found it on Goolge.

Comment: Thanks, but my concern is not on copy's implementation (I can hardcode the object's copy), but focus on a convention/interface (e.g. method signature, plus how to call & use). Just like if the community has some popular projects/packages that have this copy mechanism to follow, I want to follow it